# Asp.net 4.0 url routing

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the .Net 4.0 framework and doing some url routing. This is not an MVC project, but a webforms project. I've created two routes in the Global.asax like so:

```
        routes.MapPageRoute(
           "review",      // Route name
           "documents/{type}",      // Route URL
           "~/default.aspx" // Web page to handle route
        );

        routes.MapPageRoute(
           "help",      // Route name
           "resource/help",      // Route URL
           "~/help.aspx" // Web page to handle route
        );
```

When I click on a link in the sites navigation like 'documents/pending' it will go to the proper place and display the expected url. If I click again on 'document/accepted' the url will look like:

```
http://localhost/documents/documents/accepted
```

Also the page is not found and rendered. Same thing will happen if I click the help link then documents. The url will look like:

```
http://localhost/resource/documents/pending
```

Why is routing concatenating the url? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem's to do with how your URLs are being resolved. For ways to guarantee your URLs are always resolved correctly see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx.

Alternatively, I've written a Navigation project that will make your life much easier because it handles all URL building for you, http://navigation.codeplex.com/ . If you're interested and want any help, just let me know.

Comment: thanks man, i resolved my problem.Instead <href="link"/> i use <%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/link")%>